# Construct a Numpy array from a hexadecimal string

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a hexadecimal string `"89-50-4E-47-0D-0A-1A-0A-00-00-00-0D-49"` to be specific this will contain the data of an image.

I want to convert it to a Numpy array or possibly reconstruct an OpenCV image from the said data.

The width and height will also be supplied so the dimensions of the Numpy array is known.

How can I construct a Numpy array from the above string?

Comment: `np.array([int(x, 16) for x in "89-50-4E-47-0D-0A-1A-0A-00-00-00-0D-49".split("-")])`

Comment: what are the dimensions for above string?

Comment: @PatrickArtner it's a function so the dimensions will be supplied during run time. It will construct a 2D array with rows and columns as height and width.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could use `np.fromiter`, and cast the individual strings to hexadecimal, using the `base` argument in [`int`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html?highlight=int#int), and then to integer type using the `dtype` argument in `np.fromiter`:

```
s = "89-50-4E-47-0D-0A-1A-0A-00-00-00-0D-49"

np.fromiter((int(x, 16) for x in s.split('-')), dtype=np.int32)
# array([137,  80,  78,  71,  13,  10,  26,  10,   0,   0,   0,  13,  73])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) and the built-in [`int`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=int#int) module to convert from hexadecimal to decimal the splitted string:

```
import numpy as np

hex_string = '89-50-4E-47-0D-0A-1A-0A-00-00-00-0D-49'
np.array([int(x, base=16) for x in hex_string.split('-')])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `split` the string by dash and convert individual base-16 numbers into `int`.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> hext_str = "89-50-4E-47-0D-0A-1A-0A-00-00-00-0D-49"
>>> np.array([int(x, 16) for x in hex_str.split("-")])
array([137,  80,  78,  71,  13,  10,  26,  10,   0,   0,   0,  13,  73])
```

Provided that `(n, m)` are dimensions of your image you can use on the result the `.reshape((n, m))` method of `np.array`.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([int(x, 16) for x in "89-50-4E-47-0D-0A-1A-0A-00-00-00-0D-49".split("-")])
print(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

If memory efficiency is of concern two digits in a hexadecimal number corresponds to an unsigned 8-bit integer (ie, numbers between 0 and 255).

To return to the original string you can use `format(number, '02x')` (zero padded 2-length hexadecimal number string)

```py
hex_str = "89-50-4E-47-0D-0A-1A-0A-00-00-00-0D-49"
arr = np.fromiter((int(x, 16) for x in hex_str.split('-')), dtype=np.uint8)
# array([137,  80,  78,  71,  13,  10,  26,  10,   0,   0,   0,  13,  73],
      dtype=uint8)
```

The array would only take up 13 bytes of space, as opposed to the default array type for integers (np.int64) which would take up 104 bytes.

Once could return it to its original string form in the following way:

```py
hex_str = '-'.join((format(x, '02x') for x in arr)).upper()
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use `bytes.fromhex` along with `np.frombuffer`

```py
import numpy as np

hex_string = "ff01"
arr = np.frombuffer(bytes.fromhex(hex_string), dtype=np.uint8)
# array([255,   1], dtype=uint8)
```

in your case

```py
import numpy as np

hex_string = "89-50-4E-47-0D-0A-1A-0A-00-00-00-0D-49"
arr = np.frombuffer(bytes.fromhex(hex_string.replace("-", "")), dtype=np.uint8)
```